# VB run code on start of the application

Tags: vb6

I am a Java programmer and don't know much about VB.

**My task:**
Create an exe. When I run the exe it will read a text file, and after that it will display the content. After that the application code ends.

**What i have done:**
I have created a project and created a button on the form. On click of the button I have given the option to read.

**Problem**
I am not able to find the event which has to be used to run code on start up and code to end the application when my task completes.

Please help me with the process which I have to follow. If the code is provided, it's best, but if somebody knows any web resources it will also be a great help.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a Visual Basic 6 program to run without any form.

You need to create a module. Put a Public Sub Main inside of it.

Then in under Project Properties, General Tab; change the startup object to be Sub Main.

Answer (score 3):

To do something at form's start up, use `Form_Load()` event.

To close a form, use `unload me`.

To close your application, use `end`.

Hope this solves your problem. If not, you are welcome for further queries.

Comment: i have problem that i dont want to add any form....user should not be awaire that i am running any exe......

Comment: the exe should start run and end as this exe will be envoked from my java application

Comment: So you want a formless program? Then write your code in sub main in a Module (can be added from Project menu, Add Module). Then set Start up object to Sub Main in Project Properties dialog (can be accessed from Project menu).

Comment: @"the exe should start run and end as this exe will be envoked from my java application"

Write your code the following way;

Sub Main()

    ' Your code goes here

    end
End Sub

Don't forget to set the Startup Object  to Sub Main on Project Properties.

Comment: Don't use End statement in VB6 code, this skips all normal application shutdown tasks. Normal VB6 program will close after unloading all forms; invisible program (using Sub Main) does just close after Sub Main is finished.

Comment: Thanks Arvo for this extensive info.